# Generate dummies in Stata vs. in R

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

**Stata**

`r`, `u`, `s` are dummies. I'm wondering if the following line is also generating dummy `n`, if `r` or `u` or `s ==1`, but just omit `==1` after `r`, `u`, `s`?

`generate byte   n =  r | u | s`

**R**

Does it make a difference when we generate `byte` and `variable` in R or it's the same in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer addresses Stata questions only.

In Stata if `r u s` are all 0, 1 variables then `r | u | s` is also 0, 1 and will be 1 if any of those is 1 and 0 if and only if all are 0. So, it is equivalent to `max(r, u, s)`.

But watch out if `r u s` are 0, 1 or missing, then `r | u | s` will also be 1 if any of those is missing. But `max(r, u, s)` will be missing only if all of those are missing.

If missings are present, then you could use

```
  * 1 
  gen n = r | u | s if !missing(r, u, s)
```

The result will be 1 if any argument `r u s` is 1, 0 if all arguments are 0, and missing if any argument is missing.

```
  * 2 
  gen n = (r == 1) | (u == 1) | (s == 1)
```

The result will be  1 if any argument is 1 and 0 otherwise. "Otherwise" is anything from all 0s to all missings.

```
  * 3 
  gen n = inlist(1, r, u, s)
```

#3 is equivalent to #2.

In all cases, specifying `byte` is good practice to save on storage, but not material otherwise.